# How do you setup mutt for a KolabNow email address?

Tags: command-line, email, mutt

I use KolabNow for my email needs rather than other services like Gmail or Outlook. I spend a lot of my time in the terminal and I am hoping to setup a way to read and send emails without leaving the terminal.

So far I have read a tutorial made for Gmail but I have entered the details provided [here](https://kolabnow.com/clients/others) by KolabNow instead.

Here's my muttrc file:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes
set imap_user = 'jacksewell@kolabnow.ch'
set imap_pass = ''
set from='jacksewell@kolabnow.ch'
set realname='Jack Sewell'
set folder = imap://imap.kolabnow.com/
set spoolfile = imap://imap.kolabnow.com/INBOX

set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"
set smtp_url = 'smtp://smtp.kolabnow.com/'
set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
```

Here's the output when I try to send mail:

```
This certificate belongs to:
*.kolabnow.com

Domain Control Validated


This certificate was issued by:
 COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 COMODO CA Limited

 Salford  Greater Manchester  GB

This certificate is valid
from Wed, 28 Dec 2016 00:00:00 UTC
to Fri, 26 Jan 2018 23:59:59 UTC
SHA1 Fingerprint: AD00 8907 9BFB 568E 4C40 C99C 190E 01C0 6438 0018
MD5 Fingerprint: 7E2B 4E72 4A08 59DC 5803 D4CE 7326 7333

WARNING: Server hostname does not match certificate
```

Do I need additional software installed/configured?

Comment: @dessert, yes I am asking how you would setup an email client. I'm wanting to have it so I can check and send emails (not just the single email) from my terminal.

Comment: @dessert, I have edited the OP.

Comment: What happens when you try to send yourself a message? The only way to really know is to **Test!**.

Comment: That's too hard to read. Please Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/975544/edit your post, paste the text in, select the text and click on `{}`.

Comment: @waltinator

I have edited the OP. I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: Neither did I know `mutt` before doing the research for this nor did I test this configuration, I just combined information from the cited sources here. There is a chance this is folderol.</sub>

I'd just take a minimal configuration and change only the crucial settings first. With the information from [kolabnow.ch](https://kolabnow.ch/clients/others) let's use the one on [dev.mutt.org](https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseIMAP) and adapth it with the help of [the extensive manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) to build a simplistic `~/.muttrc`:

```
# IMAP settings, automatically log in to this mailbox at startup
set spoolfile = "imaps://jacksewell@kolabnow.ch:PASSWORD@imap.kolabnow.com:143/INBOX"

# SMTP settings
set smtp_url  = "smtps://jacksewell@kolabnow.ch:PASSWORD@smtp.kolabnow.com:587"

# Define the “=” shortcut and the entry point for the folder browser (c?)
set folder    = "imaps://imap.kolabnow.com/INBOX"
set record    = "=Sent"
set postponed = "=Drafts"
```

This uses the neat [URL syntax](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#url-syntax) where we can cram the whole information needed to communicate with the server in one single command, I did that leaving just `PASSWORD` for you to replace. If you want `mutt` to ask for your password, remove `:PASSWORD` from both lines. If you decide to store your password in `~/.muttrc` don't forget to adjust the file permissions with `chmod 600 ~/.muttrc`, this prevents others from reading it. Depending on where your mail is stored on the server you might have to adapt the `/INBOX` path:

> If your folders are addressed as sub-folders of your INBOX folder, INBOX should be given as the mailbox component, otherwise leave it empty.

Once you got the correct connection settings you're free to configure `mutt`'s behaviour to your needs, the manual I linked above seems like a good place to start. Additionally, there's the [MuttrcBuilder](https://lukeross.github.io/MuttrcBuilder/) and the [config tricks](https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/ConfigTricks).

Comment: Now I feel like using `mutt` myself. :(

Comment: Thank you @dessert. This seems to work but when I send an email and fill in my details mutt displays "Logging in... then does nothing.

Comment: Also, when launching mutt it displays: `gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received`.

Comment: I have opened a new questions for the new issues I've ran into: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975831/mutt-email-client-not-retrieving-or-sending-emails

Answer (score 1):

This .muttrc works for me with kolabnow.com. You would have to change your server to kolabnow.ch

```
set my_server       =   imap.kolabnow.com
set my_smtp_server  =   smtp.kolabnow.com
set my_user         =   USERNAME@kolabnow.com
set my_pass         =   PASSWORD

set record          =   "imaps://$my_server/INBOX.Sent Items"
set postponed       =   "imaps://$my_server/INBOX.Drafts"

set from            =   "USERNAME@kolabnow.com"

# Account - SMTP

set smtp_url        = "smtp://$my_user:$my_pass@$my_smtp_server:587"
set smtp_pass       = $my_pass
set imap_user       = $my_user
set imap_pass       = $my_pass
set ssl_force_tls   = yes
set ssl_starttls    = no

#
# Default inbox
#
set spoolfile=imaps://$my_server/INBOX

#
# Default location of mailboxes
#
set folder=imaps://$my_server/INBOX
```